# does anyone have a recipe for a Drupal 8 Views Calendar to show civi events or civi activities

Tags: civievent, activities, drupal-views, drupal-8, calendar

Title pretty much says it. want a View Calendar for Civi Event and also for Civi Activity using drupal 8

Was following the second recipe at https://evolvingweb.ca/blog/creating-events-calendar-drupal-8 but get to part for Contextual Filters and don't have the CiviEvent date fields available to me

Comment: I give this go with Drupal 8.9.3 and CiviCRM 5.35 and latest CiviCRM entities. The contextual argument appears, but does not work. Drupal Calendar provides custom calendar arguments such as F Y  eg March/2021 as an argument for the Month display, and so on. These are just not available to Activities dates. Even if you choose the activity date time, the Basic Validation fails.

Comment: Two years + after the original question, does anyone know if this is still the case? Can Drupal's Calendar module display CiviEvents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somebody who is searching for this answer can use the following civcrm extensions.

> https://civicrm.org/extensions/event-calendar-extension and
>
> https://civicrm.org/blog/totten/experimenting-activity-calendars

I have not tested "Activity Calendars" though.

Comment: Have you tested event-calendar-extension on D8?

Comment: Yes, working well for me. 3.1v.